# How to compute the inverse of a polynomial under $GF(2^8)$?

Tags: encryption, aes

It's well known that AES cryptography algorithm uses Galois Field $GF(2^8)$ multiplication to process the step MixColumn, and each column of the 4x4 matrix on encrypting should multiply the polynomial $3X^3 + X^2 + X + 2$ which is usually notated as an array $\{\tt 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02\}$, while on decrypting, the matrix should multiply the inverse of the polynominal mentioned above, namely $\texttt{0x0B}X^3 + \texttt{0x0D}X^2 + \texttt{0x09}X + \texttt{0x0E}$ which can also notated as an array $\{\tt 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x09, 0x0E\}$.

Now I wonder If only one polynomial is known, e.g. $\{\tt 0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02\}$, how can I compute its inverse mod $(X^4 + 1)$, namely $\{\tt 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x09, 0x0E\}$, and vice versa.

Answer (score 8):

The classic generic algorithm for computing modular inverses is the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). The algorithm is primarily defined for *integers*, but in fact it works for all rings where you can define a notion of Euclidean division (i.e. "Euclidean domains"). In particular it works with polynomials whose coefficients are in any field.

Let $K$ be a field. In the case of AES, this is $\mathbb{F}_2^8$, the finite field with 256 elements, but this does not actually matter here. $K[X]$ is then the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $K$. Given two such polynomials $A$ and $B$, you can find polynomials $Q$ and $R$ such that $A = BQ + R$, and the degree of $R$ (the largest power of $X$ for which the corresponding coefficient of $R$ is non-zero) is strictly less than the degree of $B$. This is easily computed in about the same way you would compute a division of integers; in fact it is easier because there is no carry to propagate between coefficients.

The magic part of it is that the $Q$ and $R$ polynomials are unique; i.e. for two polynomials $A$ and $B$, there is only one pair of polynomials $(Q,R)$ that matches the conditions above. Thus, the Euclidean division of polynomials is well defined, and the Extended Euclidean algorithm works.

In practice, the Extended Euclidean Algorithm is about finding the [Greatest Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor). In the context of polynomials, "greatest" means "of largest degree". Note that this GCD is defined only up to a multiplicative constant; it is often taken as convention that the GCD should have its largest non-zero coefficient equal to 1 (you can always arrange for that, because if polynomial $B$ divides polynomial $A$, then $tB$ also divides $A$ for all non-zero field elements $t$).

---

So if you have a polynomial $A$ and want to inverse it modulo $B = X^4+1$, then you run the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to obtain polynomials $U$, $V$ and $G$ such that $G$ is the GCD of $A$ and $B$, and $AU+BV = G$.

If $G$ has degree 0 (i.e. it is the constant $1$), then $A$ is invertible modulo $B$, and its inverse is $U$.

If $G$ has a non-zero degree, then this means that $A$ and $B$ can both be divided by that non-trivial polynomial, and there is no solution: $A$ is then not invertible modulo $B$.

Note that $X^4+1$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2^8$; it is equal to $(X+1)^4$. It follows that a polynomial $P$ of degree at most 3 in $\mathbb{F}_2^8$ is invertible modulo $X^4+1$ if and only $P$ is not divisible by $X+1$, i.e. $P(1) \neq 0$. For $P = 3·X^3+X^2+X+2$ (I am calling "$3$" what the AES specification denotes `0x03`), you have $P(1) = 3 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 1$ (remember, we are working in $\mathbb{F}_2^8$, so addition is XOR), so that polynomial $P$ is indeed invertible.

---

Another, completely different way of computing inverses is with modular exponentiation. The polynomials which are invertible modulo some given polynomial $B$ form a multiplicative group. If that group has order $e$, then the inverse of any invertible polynomial $A$ modulo $B$ is necessarily $A^{e-1} \pmod B$. In the case of $B = X^4+1$, the invertible polynomial modulo $B$ are all the polynomials $P$ such that $P(1) \neq 0$, so $e = 255·256^3 = 4278190080$ (this is easily seen in the following way: you can choose three coefficient arbitrarily, but for the fourth coefficient, you must avoid the one value that would make $P(1) = 0$). Therefore, to compute the inverse of a given polynomial $A$ modulo $X^4+1$, you "just" have to compute $A^{4278190079} \pmod {X^4+1}$, which can be done with a [square-and-multiple algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

That method is less efficient than the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, but possibly simpler to implement.

Comment: Would you please explain it with an example, I got stuck here since last 3 weeks. I'll be thankful to you.